# Accessing Class methods in Jinja2 templating

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

I'm using a Flask app in the backend, which is supposed to render a list of SKU (Stock Keeping Unit) codes in the frontend using a loop inside a Jinja2 template. The SKU class is as follows:

```
class SKU:
"""Class to hold SKU data returned from the database."""

def __init__(self, sku, scanned_at, actual_count, expected_count):
    """Initialize the SKU class with relevant attributes."""
    self.sku = str(sku)
    self.scanned_at = str(scanned_at)
    self.actual_count = int(actual_count)
    self.expected_count = int(expected_count)

def get_progress(self):
    """Get the SKU production progress as a percentage."""
    return ((self.actual_count / self.expected_count) *
            100 if self.expected_count != 0 else 0)
```

I have a method `get_all_skus_today()` that returns all rows in the database for today's date, as a list of `SKU` objects. I want to render this when someone accesses `/skus` with the following route:

```
@app.route("/skus")
def skus():
    """Get all SKUs for the day and render the skus.html template."""
    skus = get_all_skus_today()
    return render_template("skus.html", skus=skus)
```

The problem is that I want to show the progress value, that is the return of the function `get_progress()`, which is not a Class attribute, but a method. I want to do something like this:

```
{% for sku_row in skus %}
    {{ sku_row.sku }}
    {{ sku_row.get_progress }}
{% endfor %}
```

But this doesn't work. I want to avoid having to loop through the list of SKU objects and converting them into a tuple to then pass to the `render_template` function (which is what I was doing before).

Any help greatly appreciated - let me know if you need any further clarification.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an additional class to load and process the information from the database and create a listing of `Sku` objects:

```
import sqlite3
class _Sku:
   def __init__(self, row):
     self.__dict__ = dict(zip(row, ['_sku', 'scanned_at', 'actual_count', 'expected_count']))
   @property
   def sku(self):
      return str(self._sku)
   @property
   def get_progress(self):
     return ((int(self.actual_count) / int(self.expected_count)) *
        100 if int(self.expected_count) != 0 else 0)

class Sku:
  def __init__(self, _listing):
    self.all_vals = [_Sku(i) for i in _listing]
  def __iter__(self):
    yield from self.all_vals
  @classmethod
  def create_skus(cls, _filename='somefilename.db'):
    #if so desired, you can replace query below with your own
    return cls(sqlite3.connect(_filename).cursor().execute("SELECT scanned, actual, expected FROM skus"))
```

Then, in the app:

```
@app.route("/skus")
def skus():
  """Get all SKUs for the day and render the skus.html template."""
   return render_template("skus.html", skus=Sku.create_skus())
```

Now, the code above will enable to utilize your original templating:

```
{% for sku_row in skus %}
   {{ sku_row.sku }}
   {{ sku_row.get_progress }}
{% endfor %}
```